# executing external proccess in haskell in`main :: IO ()`

Tags: haskell

I have a function of type:
`main :: IO ()`.
I would like to execute external process, something like that:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStln  "before executing"
  execute "java -jar my.jar"
  putStln "after executing"
```

How to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`System.Process`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.4.2.0/docs/System-Process.html) module. An example:

```
import System.Process

main = do
    putStrLn "before executing"
    createProcess (proc "java" ["-jar", "my.jar"])
    putStrLn "after executing"
```